# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in example d3 code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and am trying to work through a seemingly simple [example](http://kyrandale.com/static/talks/pydata-to-the-web/index.html#/13).  The HTML in this example seems to be lacking a messages tag (?), but i am unable to correct this by inserting the tag.  in any event, the error "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**" is associated with the D3 line that is expecting a missing 'messages' element.

**demo_data.json:**

```
{'title': 'Hello World!', 'body': 'Your big, blue, roundness impresses us all.'}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    h1 {color:red}
</style>
<div id="demo">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"     charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    d3.json('demo_data.json', function(error, data){
        var demo = d3.select('#demo'),
        messages = demo.selectAll('messages').data(data).enter();
        messages.append('h1').html(function(d){ return d.title;});
        messages.append('p').html(function(d){return d.body;});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data in *demo_data.json* must be look like this

```
[{'title':'Hello World!', 'body':"Your big, blue, roundness impresses us all."}]
```

You forgot "[" and "]"

If this does not help, let me know

Comment: @ant strings on a json file use the `"` char not `'`